# Remove zigzags in the line

Tags: plotting

```
ellipsoidZ[x_, y_, t_] := -Sqrt[t^2/4 - x^2 - y^2] + 1; 
surfaceZ[x_, y_] := Piecewise[{{0.2, 0.3 <= x <= 0.7 && -0.2 <= y <= 0.2}}, 0];    
pp = 24;
mr = 5;
ContourPlot[surfaceZ[x, y] == ellipsoidZ[x, y, 1.9], {x, 0.29, 0.52}, {y, -0.21, 0.21}, ImageSize -> {400, 400}, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, ContourStyle -> Red, PlotPoints -> pp, MaxRecursion -> mr, Exclusions -> None]
```

The plot looks like below (red one). There are some zigzags on the edge when the plot is magnified. And in some my other plots, the situation is worse. It seems this problem is related to MaxRecursion. But how to modify the code to draw a smooth line?

[image]

Comment: How did you zoom in? Did you export the file? I can't seem to reproduce what you found.

Comment: I export it to pdf, and zoom in it in pdf.